# How to create own .lib file in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

You guys might thinking they are lot of questions in stack overflow based on this but the thing is that I am creating .dll file in visual studio 2010,as per I have learnt in internet lib file contain the address and dll file contain the code part.When you build the project the visual studio by itself should create the .lib,.exp,.dll etc files in the debug folder of the project but in my case only, .dll file created,but not the .lib,.exp etc can anyone solve this for me and tell where I am going wrong? answering this is surely appreciable. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c

Answer (score 1):

Right click your project, click on properties. Enter the general tab under "Configuration properties", and in the drop down menu at "Configuration Type", select "Static Library (.lib)".

Comment: The OP wants an import library .lib, not a static library .lib. See the duplicate I posted above.

Comment: Did you mark any of your DLL functions for export? That means using the dllexport keyword.

Comment: hey jBentely, thanks for reply, the thing is that,this will create static library file(.lib) but not a dynamic one. I need both .dll and .lib.

Comment: @Santosh Yes, that is why I commented. See the duplicate that I posted in a comment to your question.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP, ya i have wriiten code in my header like this:         #include<iostream>
  namespace subc{

  _declspec(dllexport) int algo();


   }  and defining in .cpp file like this :#include"hey.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace subc;

int algo(){
 int b=10;
 int c=20;
 int a=b+c;
 cout<<a;
 getchar();
 return 1;
}

Comment: from command prompt of visual studio I can able to create .lib and .dll file by help this like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jzh4ZULXsvo but why can't in visual studio application. please look in to it

Comment: @JBentley,i saw the link it's same question and the answer that link as provided I have worked it in the same procedure,then also I am not able to generate .lib and .dll files in my debug of project.

Comment: @Santosh Ok, but if you want an import library then why have you marked this answer as accepted when it is talking about a static library, and you yourself have said the answer doesn't solve your problem? You're just creating confusion for future readers of this question, making it look like the problem was solved when it wasn't.

Comment: ya sry,at once i thought it's gud solution, but after i worked on it,it won't worked for me and i forget to change the accepted answer  sign back to unsolved..sry again