# Is it possible to build a DLL and Import library without __declspec( dllexport )?

Tags: c++, dll

I'd like to get [this library](http://libmodbus.org/) working on Windows. At some point in the past, judging by the readme.win32 file [here](https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/tree/master/src/win32), it compiled "out of the box" on either MS Visual Studio 2008 (or 2005 with only a change of version number).

So far, none of my attempts to recreate this result have been successful - they have all ended with a DLL file being generated, but no accompanying .lib (Import Library) file. Reading the likes of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c) emphasises that the .lib file won't be produced unless there are some exported functions, and to get the exported functions, you need to use `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Searching the source code in this project, I can't find `__declspec(dllexport)` anywhere. Is there any way that an Import Library (.lib) could have ever been produced without using `__declspec(dllexport)`? Or could there be clever ways to hide this directive that have evaded my search?

Comment: In the github code. `MODBUS_API` will need to be defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using it.

Comment: Duh! Somehow I have managed to get an older version of parts of the source code loaded into my Visual Studio project. The new version has `__declspec(dllexport)` clearly used. Can I withdraw my question in embarrassment? Thanks! :-)