# Visual Studio outputs .obj but not .lib

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a large Visual Studio project with C and C++ code. The Target Extension is .dll and the Configuration Type is Dynamic Link Library. It builds the .dll just fine and outputs tons of .obj files. How do I get Visual Studio to give me one .lib (object library) file instead of tons of .obj files?

I've tried [entering a value for the Import Library option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584066/1241782) but it doesn't change anything. I need the .lib because when I create a new test program referencing my .dll I get tons of `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol` errors, which indicates that I need the object library.

Close vote: this question is **well within** [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: If it creates a .dll but not a .lib, that *usually* means that you haven't exported anything from your dll.

Comment: You will *always* get .obj files, the compiler needs to create them.  Then they get linked to produce the final .dll file.  If you don't see a .lib file at all then you forgot to export anything.  Use `__declspec(dllexport)` or a .def file.

Comment: @HansPassant I need to export the entire project. I'm trying to create a library that can be used by another application. Does Visual Studio have an option to export the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Does your dll have any actual exports? If there are no , the linker will not generate an import library .lib file.