# Which properties of project should change for using __declspec(dllexport) to create .lib file?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I want to create a DLL project and add it implicitly to a win32 app. I have a header.h file and a func.c file to generate DLL. 
header.h:

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <header.h>

#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

LIBRARY_API VOID __cdecl MyFunction(WCHAR *wchSource, WCHAR *wchDestination, WCHAR *wchKey);
```

and func.c:

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>

VOID MyFunction(WCHAR *wchSource, WCHAR *wchDestination, WCHAR *wchKey)
{
    // Some code here.
}
```

so my project builds DLL successfully but there is no .lib file beside it.
Is my code wrong or I should change some properties of my project? Maybe in Linker part?
My project is in visual studio 2010.

Comment: Do you include the header file anywhere in your DLL project? If not, then how would the compiler know what functions to export, since it will never see the declaration with the `__declspec(dllexport)` specifier.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c? Or even a duplicate to?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the header file to project. is that what you mean?

Comment: Just adding it doesn't mean the compiler will compile it (header files are not normally compiled). You actually need to `#include` it in one of the projects source files.

Comment: @alk I saw that link before but I couldn't find out what should I do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, OK I add it but no difference happened.

Comment: what should I add to: Configuration Properties/Linker/Advanced/Import Library?