meson windows dll setup
i have a meson project with a an engine [compiled as a shared_library] and a game [compiled as an executable]. the setup i want is the following:
the engine gets compiled into a .dll file which is then linked at runtime by game.exe.
i've learned [and this might be wrong] that to do this on windows, you need to compile your library into both a dll file holding the function & class implementations, and an import library [.lib] which you link into your application during compilation.
i didn't find a proper way to compile one codebase into a dll and a lib, where the lib isn't a full version of the library but simply a means to link the dll at runtime.
if i have the basic setup of
includes = include_directories('engine/include')

engine = shared_library(
  'luna',
  'engine/src/engine.cpp',
  include_directories: luna_includes,
  install: true
)

engine_dep = declare_dependency(
  link_with: engine,
  include_directories: luna_includes
)

executable(
  'game',
  'game/src/game.cpp',
  dependencies: [luna_dep],
  include_directories: luna_includes
)

it results in a linking error: fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'engine.lib'. and sure enough, this only results in a compiled .dll-file and doesn't provide a import-library [.lib] at all.
i really hope someone can help me by providing an example meson.build file or simply some pointers in the right direction
thanks!

Which tool-chain are you using to build your code MSVC, MinGW or some other ?

i'm using MSVC. also, an added note: if i simply try to do shared_library(), then declare a dependency for it and try to specify the dependency in the executable definition, this will result in a linking error [specifically, it can't find the .lib file [because it hasn't been generated, i checked multiple times]]

The 'dll-lib' you are talking about is called an import library. Assuming you are using Visual Studio then this answer might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c. Basically you have to mark in the code the functions you want to be exported. This will be documented on the 'Microsoft Learn' web site.

i'm well aware of __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport). my issue is that i don't know a way of creating this import-library [thanks for the tip, i didn't know the correct term] via meson. [i'm using vs code, but meson as the buildsystem, and am not dealing with any sln files which visual studio might provide]

@random_ab_user OK well that's outside of my knowledge. BTW using an import library is not the only way, you can also use GetProcAddress to access functions exported from a DLL. In fact all an import library really is, is a bunch of calls to GetProcAddress.
