# get a dll name from import library

Tags: windows, winapi

lets say I have an import library (.lib file) and I want to find out the dll name that this import library contains. 
from this question I know its possible to get it via dumpbin :

[When building a DLL file, does the generated LIB file contain the DLL name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477461/when-building-a-dll-file-does-the-generated-lib-file-contain-the-dll-name)

but is there any way to programatically retrieve the dll name from the lib (without invoking dumpbin)?

Comment: Find an open source COFF library, or an open source dumpbin equivalent and read the code.

Comment: Or OMF, as not all compilers use COFF on Windows.

Comment: the import library have no any single dll name. this is per linker member (symbol). so possible have many different dll names in single import library, despite i never view this in real libs